# jQuery Slider - Adding Autoplay Option

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, carousel, slideshow

I'm using a jQuery slideshow plugin but it doesn't have an option for autoplay.  Currently, the only way to trigger the slides is by clicking the left and right arrows.

Anyone have any solutions? I did some research but couldn't find anyone who came up with a solution yet and the original developer doesn't appear to be coding anymore.

Below is the slider I'm using on [codepen](https://codepen.io/lucasmotta/pen/ujKbF).

```js
(function() {
  var carouselContent, carouselIndex, carouselLength, firstClone, firstItem, isAnimating, itemWidth, lastClone, lastItem;

  carouselContent = $(".carousel__content");
  carouselIndex = 0;
  carouselLength = carouselContent.children().length;
  isAnimating = false;
  itemWidth = 100 / carouselLength;
  firstItem = $(carouselContent.children()[0]);
  lastItem = $(carouselContent.children()[carouselLength - 1]);
  firstClone = null;
  lastClone = null;
  carouselContent.css("width", carouselLength * 100 + "%");
  carouselContent.transition({
    x: (carouselIndex * -itemWidth) + "%"
  }, 0);
  $.each(carouselContent.children(), function() {
    return $(this).css("width", itemWidth + "%");
  });

  $(".nav--left").on("click", function() {
    if (isAnimating) {
      return;
    }
    isAnimating = true;
    carouselIndex--;
    if (carouselIndex === -1) {
      lastItem.prependTo(carouselContent);
      carouselContent.transition({
        x: ((carouselIndex + 2) * -itemWidth) + "%"
      }, 0);
      return carouselContent.transition({
        x: ((carouselIndex + 1) * -itemWidth) + "%"
      }, 1000, "easeInOutExpo", function() {
        carouselIndex = carouselLength - 1;
        lastItem.appendTo(carouselContent);
        carouselContent.transition({
          x: (carouselIndex * -itemWidth) + "%"
        }, 0);
        return isAnimating = false;
      });
    } else {
      return carouselContent.transition({
        x: (carouselIndex * -itemWidth) + "%"
      }, 1000, "easeInOutExpo", function() {
        return isAnimating = false;
      });
    }
  });

  $(".nav--right").on("click", function() {
    if (isAnimating) {
      return;
    }
    isAnimating = true;
    carouselIndex++;
    return carouselContent.transition({
      x: (carouselIndex * -itemWidth) + "%"
    }, 1000, "easeInOutExpo", function() {
      isAnimating = false;
      if (firstClone) {
        carouselIndex = 0;
        carouselContent.transition({
          x: (carouselIndex * -itemWidth) + "%"
        }, 0);
        firstClone.remove();
        firstClone = null;
        carouselLength = carouselContent.children().length;
        itemWidth = 100 / carouselLength;
        carouselContent.css("width", carouselLength * 100 + "%");
        $.each(carouselContent.children(), function() {
          return $(this).css("width", itemWidth + "%");
        });
        return;
      }
      if (carouselIndex === carouselLength - 1) {
        carouselLength++;
        itemWidth = 100 / carouselLength;
        firstClone = firstItem.clone();
        firstClone.addClass("clone");
        firstClone.appendTo(carouselContent);
        carouselContent.css("width", carouselLength * 100 + "%");
        $.each(carouselContent.children(), function() {
          return $(this).css("width", itemWidth + "%");
        });
        return carouselContent.transition({
          x: (carouselIndex * -itemWidth) + "%"
        }, 0);
      }
    });
  });

}).call(this);
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html {
  font-family: "europa-1","europa-2", sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 940px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/**
 * Use this wrapper only for demo purposes
 * So you can show the items outside the wrapper
 */
.wrapper--demo {
  overflow: visible;
}
.wrapper--demo:after, .wrapper--demo:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 800px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  z-index: 2;
}
.wrapper--demo:before {
  left: -800px;
}

.carousel {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.carousel .carousel__content {
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.carousel .carousel__content .item {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.carousel .carousel__content .item .title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  margin: -33px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 3rem;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: .3rem;
  color: #FFF;
}
.carousel .carousel__content .item .title--sub {
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  opacity: .5;
}
.carousel .carousel__content .item img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.carousel .carousel__nav {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -17px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.carousel .carousel__nav .nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  color: #000;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: .8rem;
  transition: padding .25s ease;
}
.carousel .carousel__nav .nav:hover {
  padding: 8px 20px;
}
.carousel .carousel__nav .nav--left {
  border-radius: 0px 3px 3px 0px;
}
.carousel .carousel__nav .nav--right {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0px 0px 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.transit/0.9.9/jquery.transit.min.js"></script>


<div class="wrapper wrapper--demo">
 <div class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel__content">
   <div class="item">
        <p class="title">First</p>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1800x850/70AD96/FFF&text=&nbsp;" alt="">
      </div>
   <div class="item">
        <p class="title">Second</p>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1800x850/EA4E23/FFF&text=&nbsp;" alt="">
      </div>
   <div class="item">
        <p class="title">Third</p>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1800x850/9BA452/FFF&text=&nbsp;" alt="">
      </div>
   <div class="item">
        <p class="title">Fourth</p>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1800x850/472D38/FFF&text=&nbsp;" alt="">
      </div>
   <div class="item">
        <p class="title">Fifth</p>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1800x850/F77C85/FFF&text=&nbsp;" alt="">
      </div>
   <div class="item">
        <p class="title">Sixth</p>
        <p class="title title--sub">Last Item</p>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1800x850/00FFAE/FFF&text=&nbsp;" alt="">
      </div>
  </div>
    
    <div class="carousel__nav">
      <a href="#" class="nav nav--left">Previous</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav nav--right">Next</a>
    </div>
    
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a **Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help keeping Stack Overflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer.

Comment: Did you check my answer? should work as you want it to! If you miss something feel free to leave a comment... regards :)

Comment: Thanks Axel, works like a charm!

Comment: Was a pleasure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use jQuery `.click()` to mimic user click on the corresponding DOM element which is `$(".nav--left").click()` & `$(".nav--right").click()` in your case.
2. Use `setInterval` to achieve the desired "autplay effect".

---

This should do it quick and dirty; just **append it to your existing script**. Have fun with this [working Forked PEN](https://codepen.io/elstermann/pen/bojyjb?editors=0010) (there is also a link to an advanced one at the bottom).

JavaScript:

```
var autoSlide = function( sDirection ) {
    sDirection === 'left' || sDirection = 'right';
    $( '.nav--' + sDirection ).click(); // ".nav--left" or ".nav--right"
};

setInterval( function() {
    autoSlide(); // with default direction: 'right'
    // autoSlide( 'left' ) // slide left 
}, 1000 ); // every 1000 milliseconds
```

CoffeeScript:

```
autoSlide = ( sDirection ) ->
    sDirection == 'left' || sDirection = 'right'
    $( ".nav--#{sDirection}" ).click()

setInterval(
    -> autoSlide() # with default direction: 'right'
    # autoSlide( 'left' ) # slide left
    1000 # every second
)
```

*I only posted whats new instead of repeating your answers snippet! If you have any questions about customization or general functionality feel free to leave a comment.*

---

[PEN with advanced control capabilities.](https://codepen.io/elstermann/pen/JrBQWm?editors=0010)

---

shortened version (reduced to the very essential):

```
setInterval(function() { $('.nav--right').click() }, 1000 );
```

or for the other direction and as half as slow:

```
setInterval(function() { $('.nav--left').click() }, 2000 );
```